# Input string was not in a correct format from an XSLT

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, umbraco

I'm getting the error "Server Error in '/' Application. Input string was not in a correct format." when viewing a page from Umbraco that has the XSLT below inserted.

I think it is being caused by trying to convert a string to a number in this XSLT file.  Probably from this line:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($rteLinkText) != 0 and string($rteLink) = number($rteLink)">
```

If I remove the XSLT from the page it renders fine.

I just wanted to check with anyone who knows XSLT that I wasn't missing anything obvious.

Thanks for taking a look!

Full code of the XSLT below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library"
  exclude-result-prefixes="umbraco.library ">

  <xsl:import href="../xslt/globalFunctions.xslt" />

  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
  <xsl:param name="rteImage" select="/macro/rteImage" />
  <xsl:param name="rteText" select="/macro/rteText" />
  <xsl:param name="rteAuthor" select="/macro/rteAuthor" />
  <xsl:param name="rteLinkText" select="/macro/rteLinkText" />
  <xsl:param name="rteLink" select="/macro/rteLink" />
  <xsl:param name="rteDonationText" select="/macro/rteDonationText" />
  <xsl:param name="rteDonationLinkText" select="/macro/rteDonationLinkText" />
  <xsl:param name="rteDonationLink" select="/macro/rteDonationLink" />

 <xsl:template match="/">

    <blockquote class="quote">
      <xsl:variable name="imageRaw">
        <xsl:call-template name="getImageUrlfromXML">
          <xsl:with-param name="mediaItemXML" select="$rteImage/Image"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="height" />
          <xsl:with-param name="width" select="'100'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($imageRaw) != 0">
        <img class="thumbImg" src="{$imageRaw}" />
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($rteText) != 0">
        <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="$rteText"/>
        </p>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($rteAuthor) != 0">
        <h4 class="quotee">
          <xsl:value-of select="$rteAuthor"/>
        </h4>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($rteLinkText) != 0 and string($rteLink) = number($rteLink)">
        <a class="quoteLink" href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl($rteLink)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="$rteLinkText"/>
        </a>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($rteDonationText) != 0 or (string-length($rteDonationLinkText) != 0 and string-length    ($rteDonationLink) != 0)">
        <div class="helpUs">
          <xsl:if test="string-length($rteDonationText) != 0">
            <h2>
              <xsl:value-of select="$rteDonationText"/>
            </h2>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="string-length($rteDonationLinkText) != 0 and string-length($rteDonationLink) != 0">
            <a href="{$rteDonationLink}" target="_blank" class="donateBtn">
              <xsl:value-of select="$rteDonationLinkText"/>
            </a>
          </xsl:if>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>

    </blockquote>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's possible the XSLT can't find the globalFucntions.xslt, but the url looks fine to me.

Comment: It's possible this is due to folder permissions on the server.
I'm not in the position yet to check or change anything but will report back as and when I can.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is this part of your logic:

```
string($rteLink) = number($rteLink)
```

those two will never be equal,  as they're different types (one numeric and one string)? It's also possible that the $rteLink variable can't be cast to a number.

Should it not be something like:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length($rteLinkText) != 0 and string-length($rteLink) != 0 and number($rteLink) &gt; 0">
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0 allows comparison of a string to a number, XSLT 2.0 does not.